# ¿Algún paquete de la API de java para eliminar carpetas y archivos con windows?

Tags: java

Me he pasado horas buscando en la Api de Java alguna clase para eliminar carpetas en el sistema operativo windows, seria de gran ayuda si alguien me pudiera recomendar alguna clase que pueda usar.

Comment: ¿Has probado algo?, Buscado de como ejecutar comandos CMD desde java --> `Rmdir`

Comment: Probaste buscar con "Como borrar una carpeta en java"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) sirve tanto para eliminar carpetas como archivos, independiente del sistema operativo. Tal como dice en la documentación:

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames

Traducido:

> Una representación abstracta de rutas de archivos y directorios (carpetas)

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
File file = new File("C:\\ruta\\de\\la\\carpeta");
file.delete();
if (!file.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Carpeta eliminada.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Carpeta no eliminada.");
}
```

Si luego de ejecutar el código la carpeta aún existe, puede ser que cuando ejecutaste tu programa Java no lo hiciste con los suficientes permisos.